# view width is not changing when i rotate the view

Tags: iphone, orientation-changes

i have created a view in textfield should characters method like this. when i change my view from portrait to landscape my view width is not changing.

```
  viewForautoCompleteTableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 120, 212, 100)];
        viewForautoCompleteTableView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


        [self.view addSubview:viewForautoCompleteTableView];
        viewForautoCompleteTableView.layer.borderWidth=1;
        viewForautoCompleteTableView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Note that :**
On Rotation, `self.view.frame` size does not change but `self.view.bounds` does , and bounds represent correct values with respect to current Interface Orientation.

Comment: viewForautoCompleteTableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 120, 212, 100)];
 actually i adjusted the frame like this,not used any self.viewforautocompletetableview

Answer (score 0):

There are two points that you have to check

. Is your view( `viewForautoCompleteTableView`) allocated ?

. If you want to change the width while rotation then you have to change the width of your view in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
```

// put the condition to check for your orientation type i.e. portrait or landscape

```
CGSize newSize= CGSizeMake(newWidth,height); // setting new width here
CGRect viewFrame=viewForautoCompleteTableView.frame;
 viewFrame. size  = newSize;
 viewForautoCompleteTableView.frame=textFrame; // provide some animation if required 

}
```

Note:- Please make sure your view is allocated

Comment: is it not possible with springs and struts?

Comment: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth, is equivalent to setting the width spring in XIB interface. But as you are creating the view dynamically, the solution I provided will help you.

Comment: For a complete understanding of resizing view , the link will help you http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Comment: i don't want to give my view frame, dynamically,it  should adjusts automatically when my superview changes